# How to write a function to compute proportion for different combination of numbers (By using python 3+)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find an appropriate value for p & q to decode a hidden text of an image BMP file.
The relevant code is as follows:

```
def est_extract():

    image_byte_array = est_get_bytes_containing_message()

    header_len = 54

# CODE TO FIND THE CORRECT VALUES OF p and q


# ********************************************************

   message_bit_array = est_extract_bits_from_image(
    image_byte_array, header_len, p, q )

    message_byte_array = est_convert_bits_to_bytes( message_bit_array )

    est_write_message_text( message_byte_array )

if __name__ == '__main__':

    est_extract()
```

I am struggling with the code to find the appropriate value of p and q. And I need to do it by maintaining the following steps:

1. I need to write a function called `est_bit_proportion` which takes a Python array as an argument and computes the proportion of ones in it. And I am going to apply this to the existing `message_bit_array` for a particular choice of values for `p` and `q`.
2. A code which will try different values of p and q, namely all combinations of `p = 1, 2, 3` and `q = 1, 2, 3.` There are thus nine combinations which I am going to try.
3. For each combination of p and q, you are going to run function `est_bit_proportion` to find the proportion of ones.
4. If the proportion of ones for some combination is less than 1 and greater than 0.5, I have the answer. Save those values of p and q and continue with the loop.

So far I have tried with below-mentioned code

```
for a in range(1, 4, 1):

        for b in range(1, 4, 1):
           bp = a/b
           print( "p =", a, "q =", b, "bp =", "%6.3f" % bp)

           if (bp > .5 and bp < 1):
            p = a
            q = b
            print( "The answer is:", "p =", p, "q =", q)
```

But it's not working properly. The output is looking like below:

```
p = 1 q = 1 bp =  1.000
p = 1 q = 2 bp =  0.500
p = 1 q = 3 bp =  0.333
p = 2 q = 1 bp =  2.000
p = 2 q = 2 bp =  1.000
p = 2 q = 3 bp =  0.667
The answer is: p = 2 q = 3
p = 3 q = 1 bp =  3.000
p = 3 q = 2 bp =  1.500
p = 3 q = 3 bp =  1.000
```

But output should look like below:

```
p = 1 q = 1 bp =  1.000
p = 1 q = 2 bp =  0.500
p = 1 q = 3 bp =  0.333
p = 2 q = 1 bp =  2.000
p = 2 q = 2 bp =  1.000
p = 2 q = 3 bp =  0.667
p = 3 q = 1 bp =  3.000
p = 3 q = 2 bp =  1.500
p = 3 q = 3 bp =  1.000
The answer is: p = 2 q = 3
```

I am new in python and trying to learn it. It would be really great if someone helps me to find the appropriate way to solve it by maintaining the steps 1 to 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use a list comprehension to preserve all the answers in any format you want. And for creating the products you can use `itertools.product()`

```
In [50]: [{'p':i, 'q': j} for i, j in product(range(1, 4), range(1, 4)) if 0.5< i/j <1]
Out[50]: [{'p': 2, 'q': 3}]
```

If you also want all the results separately you can go with the following function:

```
def est_bit_proportion(arr1, arr2):
    all_results = []
    answers = []
    for i, j in product(arr1, arr2):
        bp = round(i/j, 2)
        if 0.5< i/j <1:
            answers.append({'p':i, 'q': j, 'bp': bp})
        all_results.append({'p':i, 'q': j, 'bp': bp})
    return {'all_results': all_results, 'answers': answers}
```

Demo:

```
In [65]: est_bit_proportion(range(1, 4), range(1, 4))
Out[65]: 
{'all_results': [{'p': 1, 'q': 1, 'bp': 1.0},
  {'p': 1, 'q': 2, 'bp': 0.5},
  {'p': 1, 'q': 3, 'bp': 0.33},
  {'p': 2, 'q': 1, 'bp': 2.0},
  {'p': 2, 'q': 2, 'bp': 1.0},
  {'p': 2, 'q': 3, 'bp': 0.67},
  {'p': 3, 'q': 1, 'bp': 3.0},
  {'p': 3, 'q': 2, 'bp': 1.5},
  {'p': 3, 'q': 3, 'bp': 1.0}],
 'answers': [{'p': 2, 'q': 3, 'bp': 0.67}]}
```